# Show Spinner When Teble Row Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-defined-functions

I have an a table. When i clicked the table rows , after that ajax request functions are called and then more than one tables load. I want to  show spinner while ajax methods run. So that i write code like as below.

```
$(".table-row").click(function (evt) {
   ShowSpinnerFuntion();
   var $cell = $(evt.target).closest('td'), msg;
   var id = $cell.attr("id");
   CallAjaxMethodForTable1(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable2(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable3(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable4(id);
});
```

When i execute this click function, spinner is shown after all tables are load with ajax requests. Namely ajax methods run before "ShowSpinnerFuntion()" method although i call method (show spinner) first.

I write only show  spinner function in this click function  method.Like as:

```
$(".table-row").click(function (evt) {
   ShowSpinnerFuntion();
   var $cell = $(evt.target).closest('td'), msg;
   var id = $cell.attr("id");
   //CallAjaxMethodForTable1(id);
   //CallAjaxMethodForTable2(id);
   //CallAjaxMethodForTable3(id);
   //CallAjaxMethodForTable4(id);
});
```

When i execute click function like as above, after that spinner is shown directly.
 How can i execute  spinner function before ajax request functions. How can i give priority to this javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just call required ajax functions in your row click function

```
$(".table-row").click(function (evt) {
   var $cell = $(evt.target).closest('td'), msg;
   var id = $cell.attr("id");
   CallAjaxMethodForTable1(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable2(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable3(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable4(id);
});
```

Then define the functions as below. In the beginning show the loader and on success or error hide the loader.

```
function CallAjaxMethodForTable1(){
$('.loaderImage').show();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/some_url",
        data: { id: id },                        
        success: function(data){                
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
        },
        error: function (response) {
           $(".loaderImage").hide();

       }           
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's work

```
$(".table-row").click(function (evt) {
$('.loaderImage').show();
   var $cell = $(evt.target).closest('td'), msg;
   var id = $cell.attr("id");
   CallAjaxMethodForTable1(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable2(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable3(id);
   CallAjaxMethodForTable4(id);
});



function CallAjaxMethodForTable4(){
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/some_url",
        data: { id: id },                        
        success: function(data){                
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
        },
        error: function (response) {
           $(".loaderImage").hide();

       }           
    });
}
```

and also mention this code in every method

```
 error: function (response) {
               $(".loaderImage").hide();

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

One good way to do this is via jQuery's global ajax event handlers `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()`.

> **.ajaxStart()** -
>   Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins.
>
> **.ajaxStop()** -
>   Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed.

So in your case, you can show spinner on `.ajaxStart()` and hide it on `.ajaxStop()` and don't have to worry about showing/hiding it on table click. This will be globally handled and will work for other requests too which is a good practice when loading data asynchronously.

Check the snippet for a working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //when ajax request is started
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(event, jqXHR) {
    $(".loader").show();
  });

  //when all ajax requests are completed
  $(document).ajaxStop(function(event, jqXHR) {
    $(".loader").hide();
  });

  $("#makeRequest").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loader {
  display: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-indent: -99999em;
  margin: 55px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.loader:before {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dc5c1;
  border-radius: 10.2em 0 0 10.2em;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: -0.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
  animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
}

.loader:after {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dc5c1;
  border-radius: 0 10.2em 10.2em 0;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: 5.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
  animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="makeRequest">Make a request</button>
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

````
$('.loaderImage').show();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/some_url",
        data: { id: id },  
        beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".loaderImage").show();
                },                      
        success: function(data){                
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
        },
        error: function (response) {
           $(".loaderImage").hide();

       }           
    });
}```
````