# Manual triggering of ajaxLoader in Tabulator 3.5

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I am using the tabulator version 3.5 of http://tabulator.info/. I fill the table with an ajax request. During the loading time the "loading icon" is shown. Before the ajax request for tabulator is executed I am running some check operations. During these checks I want to show the loading icon of tabulator already. Thus, is there a way of triggering on/off the loading icon manually via javascript?

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603880/show-spinner-when-teble-row-click

Answer (score 0):

In 3.5 the only way to do it would be to trigger the ajax request yourself using the ***setData*** function to trigger the load, allowing you to do what every you want before you call it.

In version 4.0 onwards you can use the ***ajaxRequestFunc*** property to override the default ajax loading function and return a promise, so you could put your logic in there and resolve the promise when you are ready:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxRequestFunc:function(url, config, params){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            //do your pre loading logic here

            var promise = table.modules.ajax.defaultLoaderPromise.call(table.modules.ajax, url, config, params)
            .then(function(data){
                resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(err){
                reject(err);
            })
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: I am on version 4, and I have a function that is making nested fetch requests (1st request is getting information required for 2nd request).  This function is referenced in `ajaxRequestFunc`.  I have the nested fetch's `then(function` parsing the response and calling `table.setData(processedResponse)` and while it populates the table it doesn't display the initial **Loading** message.

I would like the **Loading** message to come up when the table first renders, and then to disappear when the 2nd request is processed.  

Is this possible?